# Can RabbitMQ user find information about other listeners?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm using SpringBoot's AMPQ support for RabbitMQ.  IF I connect to a queue or an exchange, can I get information about the other users/nodes that are also connected?  For example, if I'm connected to a Direct exchange, can I find out the routing keys of all the listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See RabbitMQ REST API: https://rabbitmq.com/management.html#http-api. It may answer almost to all your questions: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#management-rest-api.